# Fallo con variables de entorno ionic

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic, variables-globales

Estoy aprendiendo con ionic y con una aplicación de prueba quiero generar el `.apk`.

Cuando hago:

```
ionic cordova build --release android
```

me devuelve:

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 14.0.1
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

Actualmente tengo creadas la variables:

- Variables para el usuario:

```
ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android
JAVA_HOME = D:\Archivos de programa\Java\jdk-14.0.1
```

- Variables del sistema:

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

En el `path` añadí

```
C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms
```

¿Me falta algo o hay algo erróneo? Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema indica que tienes instalado el JDK version is 14.0.1 pero se requiere el JDK 8.

Descarga e instasla el JDK 8 desde:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

debes cambiar posteriormente la variable `JAVA_HOME` pero debes definir la ruta del JDK versiòn 8 ya que actualmente tienes definido la versiòn 14.0.1 :

```
JAVA_HOME = D:\Archivos de programa\Java\jdk-14.0.1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Pensaba que el jdk 14 era también apto porque era una versión superior al jdk 8. O al menos eso parece.

Comment: Es superior al 8 pero el problema es que el SDK de Android no esta preparado para esa versión, puede soportar como máximo la versión 9 hasta el día de hoy. @JuanJosé